# Reading a variable from an Arduino to python periodically

Tags: python-3.x, arduino, wxpython, arduino-uno, plc

I have created a Wx python App that runs an event on a time interval to update GUI.

I would like to read a variable from my Arduino controller every time i execute my time interval event?
The variable from my Arduino is an int value that basically counts the number of parts a machine is making.

What serial connection module do i need in Arduino and python?
Does anyone have an example of how to do this.

Comment: I used XBee-PRO S2C Zigbee with serial connection for my projects.You can search for them.

Comment: Do I need this to read from the arduino ?
I was under the impression that arduino may have firmware to do this by itself

Comment: You can connect the arduino to your PC using the cable. Write a sketch to write on the serial (on the arduino). Then using python library (like `Serial`) read from the serial (from your PC)..